# Invoke scala program through spark mapPartitions api

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

1. I have a data csv file which 3 columns:

   ```
   2016-01-01 00:00:00.0,100000**_0**,16.2617
   2016-01-01 01:00:00.0,100000_0strong text,17.7883
   2016-01-01 02:00:00.0,100000_1,17.2842
   2016-01-01 03:00:00.0,100000_1,17.5925
   2016-01-01 04:00:00.0,100000_2,17.3967
   2016-01-01 05:00:00.0,100000_2,15.925
   2016-01-01 06:00:00.0,100000_3,16.105
   2016-01-01 07:00:00.0,100000_3,21.8633
   2016-01-01 08:00:00.0,100000_3,22.3658
   2016-01-01 09:00:00.0,100000_4,28.2042
   ```
2. I am  extracting indexes ( Index is the number after ‘_’ listed in second column ) and third column:

   ```
   inputRDD = sc.textFile(‘file location') \
       .map(lambda x : x.split(',')) \
       .map(lambda x : (str(x[1].split('_')[1]), str(x[2])))
   ```
3. My question is to how to

   - Prepare partitions based on index id. Here I have 4 distinct indexes ( 1,2,3,4). I need to make 4 partitions and
   - Map each partition has to run a scala runnable jar file

   I tried ‘mapPartitions’ spark API however it’s not working. I am new to Spark technology, can someone help me?

*Note*:

I am using pySpark to invoke mapParititions and Scala clients

Comment: Please don't ask multiple questions at the same time. Also  _it’s not working_ is not a good description. You should provide a [mcve] and exact description of the problem (traceback, unexpected output).

Comment: I could not understand "Map each partition has to run a scala runnable jar file" bit.

Comment: @AyanGuha OP probably wants something like `RDD.pipe`.

Comment: Here is the sample code workflow I am trying: def serverAgent(index, iterator):
 
 '''for x in iterator:
         #print(x)'''
 print("Called in Partition -> " + str(index))
 sc._jvm.com.myco.package1.serveclient1.serverConnector.executeScript(str(index))

 
inputRDDMapped =inputRDD.mapPartitionsWithIndex(serverAgent)
inputRDDMapped.collect()

Comment: When I execute getting: Exception: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. What is the right approach to resolve this exception?